# XGrid: How do I get pagination to match filtering?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, frontend

I am getting this bug where I move to the second or higher page of a grid and try to apply a filter, but the pagination does not send me back to the first page. The pagination works fine if I stay on the first page and try to apply it.

For example: I have 60 rows in one of my grids and am only showing 50 per page. I click to go to page 2 and filter the ID column for only rows containing "14". In my table I should have 10 rows, however the filter behavior is keeping me on page 2 and not showing any rows. Sometimes, I click to go back to the first page and the 10 rows that are supposed to appear are there. However other times, they do not show. The behavior is inconsistent.

Here is the code for the grids:

```
<XGrid
    pageSize={pageSize}
    page={page}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[25, 50, 100]}
    rowCount={listTotal}
    onPageChange={onHandlePageChange}
    onPageSizeChange={onHandlePageSizeChange}
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    paginationMode="server"
    pagination
    disableColumnResize={true}
    hideFooterSelectedRowCount={true}
/>
```